# PRAW gives 401 exception when fetching subreddit in read-only mode

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I am using PRAW package to read information from reddit. PS: The client_id, client_secret and user_agent values are passed correctly.

```
import praw
from prawcore.exceptions import ResponseException

reddit = praw.Reddit(
     client_id="xxxxxxx",
     client_secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     user_agent="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
)

print (reddit.read_only)
subreddit = reddit.subreddit("redditdev")
print(subreddit.display_name)  # output: redditdev
print(subreddit.title)         # output: reddit development
print(subreddit.description)
```

The instance reddit seems to get created successfully as I can print the value of the `read_only` attribute and the `display_name` attributes. However, when printing the `title` attribute, I get a 401 HTTP response error.

```
True
redditdev
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sanjose/PycharmProjects/pubReddit/prawC/prawMain.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(subreddit.title)         # output: reddit development
............
............
File "/Users/sanjose/PycharmProjects/pubReddit/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/prawcore/auth.py", line 36, in _post
    raise ResponseException(response)
prawcore.exceptions.ResponseException: received 401 HTTP response
```

I am intentionally not passing the user id and password as I wish to use it only in the read-only mode. Have I missed some setup or does the `title` attribute require authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I'm pretty sure it was because I made a web app rather than a script. I solved the issue by making a new reddit app (you can make a reddit app [here](https://ssl.reddit.com/prefs/apps/)) and selecting the script option instead of the web app option.